# Индексы в MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, index

Начитался про индексы, но самого главного для  себя толком не выяснил. Поделитесь советом, как вы решаете когда использовать кластерный индекс а когда не кластерный. Может у вас есть какая-то стратегия?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-2017